# Retrofit gives EOFException only the first time

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm using framework Retrofit for the first time in my Android project. 
It handles communication with a backend. Now the strangest part is that on Android 4.4 everything works like a charm. On every version below. I get a RetrofitError type java.io.EOFException. So it fails the first time and then when I push on the retry button it works. So Why is it failing the first time?

I want to fix this because it is annoying that users needs to click retry...

Does someone got a solution for this?

Comment: did any of the answer worked for you?

Comment: Both below. The OkHttp is my solution and that solved the problem.

Comment: Same problem here.  See [this ticket](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/397) that was created on the `GitHub`.

Comment: @user1007522 That also solved the problem for me, as well as sped up my requests by about fifty percent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. In Android 4.4 they work with OkHttpclient so thats the reason why it is working on 4.4 and not on the older Android versions.

To solve this add a dependency in gradle:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-tests:1.5.1'
```

and create a new client like this:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
```

add that new client to the restadapter to use this:

```
setClient(new OkClient(client))
```

The error should be solved now.

Comment: I just did `.setClient(new OkClient())`, but yeah OkHttp solved this problem as well as greatly sped up my HTTP requests.  Also, you can accept your own answer.

Comment: I think you should reference `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:x.y.z'` instead of `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-tests:x.y.z`.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, so it doesn't seem to have solves this on JellyBean.

Answer (score 0):

This bug seems to happen because of previous connexion reused. You can disable keepalive to avoid it :

```
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolve the problem.the solution was to use both OkClient and OkHttp. After adding these two libraries I set the client on Retrofit to OkHttp like that

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
.setErrorHandler(new ErrorRetrofitHandlerException())
.setEndpoint("Yout base URL")
.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
.setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient())) //Http Client 
.build();
```