# EOFException in Retrofit while executing synchronous PUT requests

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit, eofexception

In my app I make *synchronous* `PUT` requests using the Retrofit library. The problem is: sometimes the library throws `EOFException`s.

Below is a stack trace for one of such cases

```
29099-29269/com.mycompany.myapp D/Retrofit﹕ java.io.EOFException
  at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:192)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:189)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:101)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:676)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:426)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:371)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:466)
  at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.readResponse(UrlConnectionClient.java:73)
  at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.execute(UrlConnectionClient.java:38)
  at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:321)
  at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
  at $Proxy7.addEvents(Native Method)
  at com.mycompany.myapp.api.MyService.addEvents(MyService.java:59)
```

I tried the following prosposed solutions but none of them helped in my case:

- [Retrofit gives EOFException only the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22351400/249690)
- [bug retrofit.RetrofitError: java.io.EOFException for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24806797/249690)
- [1.4.0 New line in String causes retrofit.RetrofitError: java.io.EOFException](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/397)

Here is how I create `RestAdapter` in my app:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
  .setEndpoint(Url)
  .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor()
  {
      @Override
      public void intercept(RequestFacade request)
      {
          request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
          request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      }
  })
  .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))
  .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
  .setErrorHandler(new MyErrorHandler())
  .build();
```

Does any one know an other solution for the problem?

Btw, I can't use solutions involving `System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");` because I need to keep my connection alive because of performance reasons.

Comment: Is the server returning a 204 for you?

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? Similar is discussed in [issue #1114 of OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1114).

Comment: @JJD No I did not solve the problem.

Comment: @Bobrovsky I posted [my setup in the Retrofit issue #397](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/397#issuecomment-68890904) you linked yesterday. Maybe it is of help for you.

Comment: Did you use last version of okhttp?

Comment: @Bobrovsky Did you find solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This issue can commonly be caused by a network error. If it is reproducing consistently, consider the potential cause of content length and request timeout. Sometimes timed out network requests can return an improper End of File. Which would throw this error as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps EOF as lost network connection or timed out. Try increasing your timeout and ensuring keep-alive is set.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37595699/android-https-con-getresponsecode-throws-endoffile-exception-on-readutf8linest) with similar problem.

If you are with big requests (i think this is more than 50Mb of data) and you are not using pagination system in the server side, you can get this type of error.

Also it can be a TimeOut of the server side, for example.